# Separate tint colors for a tab bar on iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I have an application which uses a tab bar. I want each tab to use a different tint color. Is there a way to have each tabBarItem be selected with a different color? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a UITabBarController, you can simply implement the following delegate and change the color for each tabs as you want.

In case you aren't using the UITabBarController, just add the correct delegate to your UITabBar.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
    UIColor *colorToApply;
    switch (indexOfTab) {
        case 0:
            colorToApply = [UIColor colorWithRed: 255.0/255.0 green: 64.0/255.0 blue: 98.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
            break;
        case 1:
            colorToApply = [UIColor colorWithRed: 254.0/255.0 green: 156.0/255.0 blue: 152.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
            break;
        case 2:
            colorToApply = [UIColor colorWithRed: 250.0/255.0 green: 205.0/255.0 blue: 171.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
            break;
        case 3:
            colorToApply = [UIColor colorWithRed: 200.0/255.0 green: 200.0/255.0 blue: 168.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
            break;
        case 4:
            colorToApply = [UIColor colorWithRed: 130.0/255.0 green: 175.0/255.0 blue: 155.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    tabBar.tintColor = colorToApply;
}
```

Comment: It was hard to find this post, but finally it helped me so much. Thx !

Comment: @lucè-brùlè what would be the delegate for UITabBar?